# Recuperar argumentos de um array javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um pagina que me retorna os dados da seguinte forma:

> "teste,123mudar,*IMPEXPROS*,sarmento:172.20.1.1,172.20.1.2,172.20.1.3,172.20.1.4,172.20.1.5,172.20.1.6,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.140:"

estou fazendo uma outra pagina para manipular estes dados. Primeiramente eu recebo os dados com esta função:

```
const getDados = async () => {
  let url = 'http://' + host + '/dados';
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          var data = xhttp.responseText;
          prepareListDados(data);
      }
  }
  await xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  await xhttp.send();
}
```

Apos pegar os dados eu separo eles desta forma:

```
const prepareListDados = (dados) => {
  let arrParams = dados.split(':');
  let nomes = arrParams[0].split(',');
  let ips = arrParams[1].split(',');
  let arrDados = [];

  arrDados.push({
    ssidAP: nomes[0],
    senhaAP: nomes[1],
    ssidSTA: nomes[2],
    senhaSTA: nomes[3],
    ipLocal: ips[0],
    ipmodulo1: ips[1],
    ipmodulo2: ips[2],
    ipmodulo3: ips[3],
    ipmodulo4: ips[4],
    ipmodulo5: ips[5],
    mascaraAP: ips[6],
    gatewaySTA: ips[7],
    localSTA: ips[8],
    mascaraSTA: ips[5],
    servidorSTA: ips[5],
  });
  texto1(arrDados);
  texto2(arrDados);
}
```

após isso eu envio o array para um funcao e queria manipular os valores desse array arrDados. Coloquei desta forma mas nao esta funcionando:

```
const texto1 = (arrDados) =>{
  let a = setSSIDAP();
  let b = setSSIDSTA();

  if (a == "null" && b == "null"){
    return "null";
  }
  if(b == "null" && a != "null"){
    return a + ","+ arrDados.ssidSTA + "," + arrDados.senhaSTA;
  }
  if(a == "null" && b != "null"){
    return arrDados.ssidAP + "," + arrDados.senhaAP + "," + b;
  }
  if (a != "null" && b != "null"){
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Remetendo ao seguinte error:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'arrDados.ssidSTA')

Nao sei se estou separando certo os valores, pois podem notar que estão separados por "," e separados os blocos por ":"

Funções setSSIDAP e setSSIDSTA:

```
const setSSIDAP = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let chk = document.getElementById('bloco1');
    if (chk.checked) {
        if (validateForms('redeInterna')) {
            let localreles = getSSIDS('redeInterna');
            return localreles;
        }
    } else {
        return 'null';
    }
}
const setSSIDSTA = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let chk = document.getElementById('bloco2');
    if (chk.checked) {
        if (validateForms('staWifi')) {
            let localreles = getSSIDS('staWifi');
            return localreles;
        }
    } else {
        return 'null';
    }
}
const getSSIDS = (formId) => {
  let frm = document.getElementById(formId);
  let txt = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      txt = txt + frm.elements[i].value + ",";
  }
  let obj = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1); // remove ',' final da string e add ">"
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: seu `arrDados` é um array, não vai funcionar do jeito que está. Envie usando `texto1(arrDados[0]);` e vê se resolve

Answer (score 0):

Você cria um objeto com os dados, insere ele num array de 1 elemento e passa esse array pras funções. Ou seja, o array é totalmente desnecessário. Passe diretamente o objeto com os dados.

```
let dados = {
    ssidAP: nomes[0],
    senhaAP: nomes[1],
    ssidSTA: nomes[2],
    senhaSTA: nomes[3],
    ipLocal: ips[0],
    ipmodulo1: ips[1],
    ipmodulo2: ips[2],
    ipmodulo3: ips[3],
    ipmodulo4: ips[4],
    ipmodulo5: ips[5],
    mascaraAP: ips[6],
    gatewaySTA: ips[7],
    localSTA: ips[8],
    mascaraSTA: ips[5],
    servidorSTA: ips[5],
};

texto1(dados);
texto2(dados);
```

Comment: e recebo os valores com dados.ssidAP?

Comment: @VitorPereira Sim.

Comment: continua o mesmo error..

Comment: Se vc substituiu o código desnecessário pelo código q eu mostrei na resposta, e renomeou o parâmetro recebido pelas funções texto1 e texto2, não tem como dar aquele erro.

Comment: Fiz exatamente o que falou, e acontece o seguinte error:

Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'dados2.ssidSTA')